Issue while trying to install llama
The following is the error that I encountered while I am trying to install llama:
vs[chatbot]pip install llama 

Collecting llama
  Using cached llama-0.1.1.tar.gz (387 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/w6/wff1s8k12sj6xnprmhdvzcbr0000gn/T/pip-install-nccyet_q/llama_2ac963a55bd94dcd9a3b3ee6748adf67/setup.py", line 6, in <module>
          execfile('llama/version.py')
          ^^^^^^^^
      NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.


You are not installing the llama you think you are... the package has a different name (llama2)

Are you sure you want to install the Loss & LAtency MAtrix?

make the steps like in this article: https://medium.com/@developer.yasir.pk/getting-response-from-vicuna-model-through-api-36287789242b
